# Neovim lua unable to load config from different file

Tags: lua, neovim

I am unable to load config when using require. Form below you can see that I added 2 files under the `lua` directory

1. lua/bufferline.lua
2. lua/plugins/bufferline.lua

I am tried loading both via

```
-- Bufferline
  use {
    "akinsho/bufferline.nvim",
    tag = "v3.*",
    requires = 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons',
    config = [[require("bufferline")]]
    -- config = [[require("plugins/bufferline")]]
  } -- buffer list with icons
```

And both failed to load the `config` changes. But adding the config inline in the `plugins.lua` the config shows up when restring.

Please check below for my files

lua directory structure

```
> tree
├── bufferline.lua
├── colorscheme.lua
├── keymaps.lua
├── options.lua
├── plugins
│   └── bufferline.lua
├── plugins.lua
```

init.lua

```
require "options"
require "keymaps"
require "plugins"
require "colorscheme"
```

plugins.lua

```
--
-- Automatically install packer
local install_path = fn.stdpath "data" .. "/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim"
if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
  PACKER_BOOTSTRAP = fn.system {
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--depth",
    "1",
    "https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim",
    install_path,
  }
  print "Installing packer close and reopen Neovim..."
  vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
end

-- Autocommand that reloads neovim whenever you save the plugins.lua file
vim.cmd [[
  augroup packer_user_config
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost plugins.lua source <afile> | PackerSync
  augroup end
]]

-- Use a protected call so we don't error out on first use
local status_ok, packer = pcall(require, "packer")
if not status_ok then
  return
end

-- Have packer use a popup window
packer.init {
  display = {
    open_fn = function()
      return require("packer.util").float { border = "rounded" }
    end,
  },
}


-- Install your plugins here
return packer.startup(function(use)
  use "wbthomason/packer.nvim" -- Have packer manage itself
  use "nvim-lua/popup.nvim" -- An implementation of the Popup API from vim in Neovim
  use "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" -- Useful lua functions used ny lots of plugins

  -- Bufferline
  use {
    "akinsho/bufferline.nvim",
    tag = "v3.*",
    requires = 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons',
    config = [[require("bufferline")]]
    -- config = [[require("plugins/bufferline")]]
  } -- buffer list with icons

  -- require("bufferline").setup{
  --   options = {
  --     numbers = "buffer_id",
  --     always_show_bufferline = true,
  --     separator_style = "thin"
  --   }
  -- }

  use "christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator" -- navigate between tmux and nvim

  --
  -- Automatically set up your configuration after cloning packer.nvim
  -- Put this at the end after all plugins
  if PACKER_BOOTSTRAP then
    require("packer").sync()
  end

end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the general problem here is, that you're using the double brackets for the `config =`  option:

```lua
    config = [[require("bufferline")]]
```

As far as I know (my lua skills aren't that great) those double brackets (`[[`) are used to create a raw string in lua, so you're basically giving `config` a string which, I assume, vim tries to execute it as vimscript-code.

A solution for that is simply stick to lua and convert your `config =` line to the following:

```lua
config = function() require("bufferline") end,
```

so in total in should look like this:

```lua
-- Bufferline
  use {
    "akinsho/bufferline.nvim",
    tag = "v3.*",
    requires = 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons',
    config = function() require("bufferline") end,
  } -- buffer list with icons
```

## Important hint

You may also need to rename your `bufferline.lua` file because the module-name of the plugin [already uses the name `bufferline`](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim#usage) so `require("bufferline")` will actually get the module but not your `bufferline.lua`!